# Handling StreamReader.ReadLine() Interrupted - Server unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I have a **StreamReader** that is on a stream obtained from **WebResponse.GetResponseStream()**

**StreamReader.ReadLine()** works perfectly in normal operation, but when the server is shut down mid-communication, instead of throwing an exception as I had expected, the application just hangs at **StreamReader.ReadLine()** and CPU usage jumps to 100%

*What is the correct way to handle this loss of connectivity scenario while **StreamReader.ReadLine()** is executing?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a read timeout

```
int fiveSeconds = 5000;
streamReader.BaseStream.ReadTimeout = fiveSeconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid you can't use StreamReader like this - it will keep calling the Read on the socket in a while loop, and the Read simply returns 0, since it doesn't wait for the data. In any case, you shouldn't treat a web response as any other stream. The fact that you didn't read anything doesn't mean that there's nothing left - and you don't know how much you still have to read.

Instead, unless you're downloading a huge page, read the whole response into a MemoryStream for example, and use StreamReader on that. It's going to be much much faster, and much more stable. It just means you have to buffer the whole page in memory for a while.